# How to make wordpress spacious theme full width?

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

Currently i have large sections of whitespace on the left and right margins on all my pages which i would like to remove. I have managed to amend the width of the page using the following CSS

```
#main .inner-wrap {
max-width: 97%;
}
```

However i am having difficult finding code to amend the width of the content?
My website is www.monoalarms.co.uk/wp

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE] - links to your website do not count - [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I see a lot of current containers being set: max-width in css.

You can take a look at some classes: inner-wrap, elementor-widget-container, ...
then set:

**- max-width: 100% !important;**

**- Remove padding or margin if it needs**

Answer (score 0):

```
.inner-wrap {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.inner-wrap .elementor-container {
    max-width: 94% !important;
}
header .inner-wrap {
    padding: 0 30px;
}
```

Try With this one

Comment: Vishal, you my friend are a life saver. One quick question - will implementing this code cause me any issues regarding viewing the website on a mobile or tablet device? Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Nope... We are setting it with % so it will not cause in any device... Cheerz